# Delete button "delete" after clicking in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm showing data by ng-repeat. There Have button. to delete item.
After delete item, this button must dissapear only for  item that I deleted.

```
<tr ng-repeat="paymentinfo in paymentList | filter:keyword | filter:money | filter:getdate | filter:{state: 'archived'}: archived.state ? true : false">
  <td id="outmouse">
    <ul style="list-style: none;" class="gt-reset">
      <li class="dropdown changecoursename">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
          <span class="tableOperation norlmalstate">Open Course</span>
          <span class="tableOperation openedstate">more options</span>
          <b class="caret"></b>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a class="tableOperation" ng-click="paymentRemarks()">Remarks</a></li>
          <li><a class="tableOperation" ng-click="paymentReturn(paymentinfo)">Return</a></li>
          <li ng-switch on="paymentinfo.state">
            <div ng-switch-when="archived" class="archived__state">{{paymentinfo.state}}</div>
            <a ng-switch-default class="tableOperation" ng-click="paymentDelete();">{{deletebtn}}</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </td>
</tr>
```

There place where I need to delete

```
<li ng-switch on="paymentinfo.state">
  <div ng-switch-when="archived" class="archived__state">{{paymentinfo.state}}</div>
  <a ng-switch-default class="tableOperation" ng-click="paymentDelete();">{{deletebtn}}</a>
</li>
```

My JS

```
$scope.datas = [{
  date: '06-12-2016',
  name: 'Pinao Class',
  state: 'archived',
  remark: 'remarled',
  amount: 101,
  id: 21
}, {
  date: '15-04-2016',
  name: 'drivers Class',
  state: 'notarchived',
  remark: 'remarled',
  amount: 102,
  id: 22
}];
$scope.paymentList = $scope.datas;

$scope.deletebtn = "delete";

$scope.paymentDelete = function() {
  $scope.www = true;
  $scope.deletebtn = false;
}
```

My code deleting for All elements need delete just for one I choose

Comment: pass some unique id related to that element and delete based on that only

Comment: Can you give example?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/oymo9g2f/2/

Comment: Yes there deleting. but Idea is not remove element, the  idea to remove button delete from one element. when I removing one element another elements  change value too

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
ng-click="paymentDelete(this.paymentinfo);">// pass current object to delete function

$scope.paymentDelete = function (paymentinfo ) {
      $scope.www = true;
      var index = $scope.paymentList.indexOf(paymentinfo );
    if (index > -1) {
    $scope.paymentList.splice(index, 1);
   }
 }
```

Comment: it's deleting element,but another element's on page change the button "delete" to false. they need to have value "delete"

Comment: remove that $scope.deletebtn = false; from the function